# How do I make Windows allow Program Files to have tar.gz files copy to?

Tags: windows-10

I have seen other posts regarding how to open a tar.gz file.  But, I need to save it under Program Files which got denied when I tried to copy it to.

Screenshot[image]

The security permission has set to allowed full control thus should be allowed files to be copied there.

Hope someone can advise me. Thanks.

OS : Windows 10

Comment: Your screenshot isn’t clear (text is grainy and cannot be read). Extract the files in one location and then as an Administrator move the files to their final location. Alternatively you can run 7zip as an Administrator

Comment: Also note that if you use 7zip (one of my fav programs), the extraction will be a two step process.  file.tar.gz will decompress to become file.tar, then that will again need to be extracted.  In Linux, this second step is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Your process needs to have administrator rights in order to extract to that folder. YOu can do this in two ways:

1. Open File Explorer with administrative rights: Open the Task Manager and go to File>Run New Task. In the Create new task box, enter explorer.exe and check the 'Create this task with administrative privileges' option. Click Ok, and a new File Explorer window will open with admin rights. In such window, extract through the right-click context menu.
2. Alternatively, or should the above not work, go to the folder where your tar extractor is located. Right-click on the .exe file and choose "Run as administrator". Extract your file, the exact steps will depend on the extractor you're using.